# Can anyone tell me about WebDriverBackedSelenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know about **WebDriverBackedSelenium**
Can any one help me to know more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Webdrivbacked selenium has all the similar method names of Selenium RC but its developed using WebDriver and Weblement classes . 
There is no browserbot dependancy in WebdriverBacked Selenium.

It helps to convert existing RC project to Webdriver.

The below link shows an example how to convert

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp